# LaTex Urdu with Aeraab Issue

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I need help in URDU Script. Some Aeraab works fine, but some pronunciation symbols dislocate from their actual position. The working example is,

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7in, paperheight=9in, bindingoffset=.15in, left=0.5in,right=0.5in, top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec, bidi, bidipoem}
\renewcommand\poemcolsepskip{1cm}

\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1]{Simplified Arabic}

\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=western]{urdu}

\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5, WordSpace=5, Path=D:/My work/my own work/] {Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq.ttf}

\linespread{2.5}

%!TEX program = xelatex
\begin{document}


مُسَلّم ،   مُسلّم

 
  اِنتِقَام ،
  
   اُردُو ، 
   
   مُقَابِلہ
   
    جُرّأت،
    
     تَأثُّر،
     
      تأسُّف،
      
       مؤرِّخ،
       
        تأمُّل
        
جرّأت
\end{document}
```

Please help and guide.

Comment: It might be a font issue, but you could try adding `Language=Urdu` to the options of `\urdufont` and see if that helps, or look for a stylistic set or font with the placement you want. You do not want to reload `bidi` after `polyglossia`, and you do not want to define both `\arabicfont` and `\urdufont`.

Comment: You also don't want `fontenc` or `inputenc` in XeTeX, you don't want `color` in addition to `xcolor`, the `Scale=` on `\urdufont` should probably be `Scale=MatchUppercase`, and maybe one or two other little things. Probably not the cause of your problem, but couldn't hurt.

Comment: Does [Noto Nastaliq Urdu](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#nastaliq-aran) work?

Comment: @Davislor: Noto Nastaliq works for Aeraab but there are issues with numerals and some specific Urdu letters.

Deleted the fontenc, inputence, bidi, color, etc. but the issue does not resolve.

Comment: @Davislor : I also added the Language=Urdu and Scale=MatchUppercase

Comment: You might also try [Awamy Nastaliq](https://software.sil.org/awami/) with `Renderer=Graphite`. Many variations of the script are supported as font features.

Comment: awami nastaliq does not connect the letters even using Renderer=Graphite